# Program crashes after reading data from file using fscanf

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have written a simple program to read the content of a text file and I compiled it with cl.exe (visual studio compiler). The program compiles, and when I run it, it starts normally and the moment it goes past the reading and printing  of the data it crashes brutally... Here's my code :

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>


int main (int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
char filename[256];
char d1[9]; 
char d2[8];

if (argc > 1) //lecture de l'argument
strcpy(filename, argv[1]);
    else {
        printf("Usage: read_file");
        return 0;
    }

FILE *f = fopen(filename, "r");
if (f == NULL) {
  printf("Cannot find file \'%s\'\n", filename);
  return 0;
}

printf("file opened\n");

rewind(f);
fscanf(f, "%s %s", d1, d2);

printf("%s %s",d1,d2);
fclose(f);

return 1;
}
```

When I compile it with gcc it works just fine however. The thing is, I need this to run with visual studio compiler...

Comment: What is the contents of the file? What do you think happens if the strings you read are longer than ***8*** and ***7*** characters, respectively? (Note that those sizes I mentioned leaves space for the string terminator in your arrays)

Comment: A little advice: **Never** blame the compiler. I've found maybe 5 actual compiler bugs in my lifetime, while my own errors are beyond counting.

Comment: Bug is in your code, not Visual Studio. Your `fscanf` invocations do not account for strings of arbitrary length. Don't use what you cannot control. Remove the [tag:c] tag, and the C code just as well.

Comment: Maybe `d1` and/or `d2` are too small.

Comment: bugs in compilers are very, very, very rare.

Comment: First learn to *check* your input (I.e. the stuff you've read from the file). Then talk about compiler bugs.

Comment: Are `d1` and `d2` widths enough to store the C-string null terminator after strings chars?

Comment: With all due respect, I would put money on the bug being with your code and NOT the compiler.

Comment: Your program seems to have a split personality disorder. It can't decide whether it's C or C++.

Comment: @xaxxon be as harsh as you want, but my point still stands - it's *much* more likely for a problem to be with your own code than with the compiler, and it's a mark of inexperience to assume the opposite.

Comment: Don't ge me wrong I am  definitely not saying the problem is from the compiler. I am just trying to know what I did wrong since it works with one and not the other...

"-0.003510 0.000000" That is the line I am trying to read in the file

when compiled with cl it reads it and print it but crashes right after.

I also tried to record it as a C file and to compile with cl but the problem is the same... (and yes I remove every c++ library in the include section before)

Comment: Does the problem disappear if you make `d1` and `d2` larger?

Comment: What is the error message upon crashing?

Comment: @MarkRansom if you're doing things more advanced than this and it doesn't work in VS, it can save a lot of time to check early on and see if it's a known VS bug (or simply unimplemented C++ feature).  I've wasted hours trying to figure out what I did wrong when VS simply can't deal with something (like nested lambdas with auto return types).

Comment: @AntonyBazir: If you had posted your example input as part of the question instead of burying it in a comment, somebody could have told you you were causing undefined behavior due to out-of-bounds access half an hour ago.

Comment: @AntonyBazir _"Don't ge me wrong I am definitely not saying the problem is from the compiler."_ Then you should change your question title to something more meaningful. Also provide a [MCVE], including a detailed description of the problem and what you did observe when stepping through your program code with the debugger. After you did all that, you probably solved your problem without asking here at all.

Comment: If you want to read two floating-point numbers, why don't you actually read them as floating point numbers, instead of as strings?

Answer (score 6):

First of all, you should have posted your input example.

Anyway, as other people have stated d1 and d2 are too small and are not storing the C-Null terminator. Just make them larger (d1[10], d2[9]).

Finally, you are programming in c++ so therefore I would recommend using the c++ libraries. Your code would be simpler and would not mix c and c++.

Best regards.